# How do I populate a dropdownlist based on a selection from another dropdownlist?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

```
protected void ddlEnvironment_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ddlEnvironment.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        ddlServers.Items.Add("item1");
    }

    if (ddlEnvironment.SelectedIndex == 1)
    {
        ddlServers.Items.Add("item2");
    }

    if (ddlEnvironment.Text == "Production")
    {
    }
}
```

The above is not working. When I make a selection on ddlEnvironment and it is the first item on the list (index 0), the other dropdownlist is not upading with "item1". Why?

Comment: When you debug the code, what is the value of ddlEnvironment.SelectedIndex?

Comment: Are you check with firebug or other, if the callback is goin to the server? See Networking.

Comment: Try this: http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx - Fun AJAX Control Tool Kit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be different reasons by default dropdown list do no do postback.

- Check if you have `AutoPostBack="true"`
- You bind the ddlEnvironment in !Page.IsPostBack block so that it maintains its state on postback

  ```
  if(!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
     ddlEnvironment.AuutoPostBack = true;
     ddlEnvironment.DataSource = datasource; 
     ddlEnvironment.DataBind();
  }
  ```

Comment: it was this. it fixed the problem. thanks! :) ps. 9 mins till i can accept it

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have `AutoPostBack=true` - right?

If you're initializing ddlEnvironment in your Page_Load() event handler, it's being reset on postback.

You need to do something like this:

```
If (!Page.IsPostback)
{ 
    // initialize ddlEnvironment here 
}
```